# brute-force canonical labelling of a simple graph

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism

I am looking for an example that shows how to [canonically label](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CanonicalLabeling.html) a graph using brute-force approach. An example with a 3 vertex or 4 vertex simple graph is preferred.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *canonical labeling*?

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer exactly what you are asking.  What do you mean by brute-force approach?  Also, what research have you done?  Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_canonization and references listed there?